# Adding an unapplied payment in Quickbooks Web Connector

Tags: quickbooks

My client takes pre-payments for work done before an invoice is created, and has a need to create a payment with no applied transactions.

We can do this just fine in Quickbooks itself, however, I cannot figure out how to get the web connector to do this.

I can't seem to get a payment to go over without including some kind of transaction to apply it to.  How can I get this to work?

```
<ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="38b00162-339c-4fb8-b8f7-5f3d08042eaf">
    <ReceivePaymentAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
            <ListID>800013CF-1516038502</ListID>
            <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
            <TxnDate>2018-02-12</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>TEST PAYMENT</RefNumber>
        <TotalAmount>123.45</TotalAmount>
        <PaymentMethodRef>
            <FullName>Check</FullName>
        </PaymentMethodRef>
        <DepositToAccountRef>
            <FullName>Undeposited Funds</FullName>
        </DepositToAccountRef>
    </ReceivePaymentAdd>
</ReceivePaymentAddRq>
```

Comment: I have done this and can test with my old project if needed but could/did you try adding `<IsAutoApply >false</IsAutoApply>`?  Also what is in the response from QB when you try this?

Comment: @GMan80013 You, sir, have saved my life!!  That worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the IsAutoApply needs to be set to false.

This works:

```
<ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="38b00162-339c-4fb8-b8f7-5f3d08042eaf">
    <ReceivePaymentAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
            <ListID>800013CF-1516038502</ListID>
            <FullName>John Doe</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
            <TxnDate>2018-02-12</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>TEST PAYMENT</RefNumber>
        <TotalAmount>123.45</TotalAmount>
        <PaymentMethodRef>
            <FullName>Check</FullName>
        </PaymentMethodRef>
        <DepositToAccountRef>
            <FullName>Undeposited Funds</FullName>
        </DepositToAccountRef>
        <IsAutoApply>false</IsAutoApply>
    </ReceivePaymentAdd>
</ReceivePaymentAddRq>
```